# PHP/Krumo: accessing arrays within arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, krumo

I'm using [krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) to output data from a page, all the data is accessible through the $page variable. I have a field called customer with the following structure:

```
customer (Array, 1 element) 
    0 (Array, 1 element) 
        id (String, 2 characters ) 85
```

How do i actually access id? I've tried `$page->customer->id` but it doesn't work. On the same level as customer, there's a string field called foo which I can access using `$page->foo` - so why doesn't my approach work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding your question your solution would be:

```
$id=$page->customer[0]['id'];
```

A print_r() version would help too, maybe

Comment: Tried your suggestion, got:
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: Oh, I just saw that you are using a class - try again with what I wrote now please